# How to interrupt pselect?

Tags: c, select, signals

Here there's my code, I'm not able to interrupt the main loop using signals. When I launch the SIGUSR1 signal handler is called but I don't unblock pselect.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int end = 1;

void handler(int sig) {
    end = 1;
}

int main() {
    sigset_t blockset;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int res;

    /* Block the signal */
    sigemptyset(&blockset);
    sigaddset(&blockset, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &blockset, NULL);

    /* Install handler */
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    /* Unblock signal; wait for signal */
    while(end) {
        sigemptyset(&emptyset);    /* Signal mask to use during pselect() */
        res = pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &emptyset);
        if (errno == EINTR)
            printf("Interrupted by SIGUSR1.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, I thought it was because you were using `SA_RESTART`. That's the opposite of what you want. However, it turns out that `pselect` ignores `SA_RESTART`, so that's not it.

---

As it turns out, `pselect` *is* returning, and `errno` *is* `EINTR`. You simply didn't see the message because you didn't flush `stdout`'s buffer!

You could do that by using `fflush` after you send output to `stdout`.

```
fflush(stdout);
```

But `stdout` is line-buffered when outputting to a terminal, so simply adding the missing newline will do the trick.

```
printf("Interrupted by SIGUSR1.\n");
```

---

You wouldn't even have noticed the aforementioned problem if not for a second error. `stdout` is normally flushed on program exit, but your program doesn't exit because you have

```
int end = 1;

void handler(int sig) {
    end = 1;
}

while (end) { ... }
```

when you meant to do

```
int end = 0;

void handler(int sig) {
    end = 1;
}

while (!end) { ... }
```

Comment: ikegami, you're right; end=1 is not correct, but also doing what you said, my code doesn't work...but I was not clear in my question: the pselect I want to stop is on a separate thread. Is it different?